# WPF Highlight multiple nodes/leaves in a treeview based on selection

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a bound, hierarchical `TreeView`.  Do to the nature of the underlying data, the same object may appear multiple times in the tree:

```
A
--A1
  ---A11
--A2
B
--B1
--A1      <<< A1 is a node under both A and B
  ---A11  <<< A11 also shows up twice since it is a child of A1
```

Please note that although I've shown 3 levels in my example, the real data can have an unlimited number of levels.  And the same object may show up in multiple levels.  My `TreeView` with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` displays this beautifully.

Since A1 may appear in multiple places, I want to highlight this to the user so that they know that editing A1 will impact not just the A branch but also the B branch.

Please note that the goal is to just HIGHLIGHT the other A1, not change the selection.

The only solution I've arrived at so far is to have an `IsHighlighted` property in the underlying class for the objects.  When A1 is selected I change the value of `IsHighlighted` through the `SelctedItemChanged` handler.  `IsHighlighted` is in turn bound to the `TreeViewItem`'s `Background` property through a converter and a GUI update is triggered by a property change notification.

The problem I have with this method is that I now have a purely UI-driven property in my model.  While I'm not following a strict adherence to MVVM, I'd like to at least keep the model a bit more isolated.

What is a suggested way of implementing this?

Comment: One option is to project your viewmodel collection/tree into a view-specialized tree of the same shape, where each node has a reference to a `VMNode` and an `IsHighlighted` flag. Two ViewNodes with references to the same VMNode would have to be duplicates themselves. Personally, I would briefly consider the limited span of time I've been allotted in this world, and use exactly the solution you've got.

Comment: What do you mean by project?

Comment: I mean to create a new collection based on the items in an existing one. Sorry, I'm not crazy about that bit of jargon but couldn't think of a better word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with a model with two properties:

- Name
- IsHighlighted

Here's why:

The logic you are talking about is, in essence, view logic, but it is not deciding *how* the view is displaying data; instead, it is only representing *what* the view is displaying. Therefore, it should reside in the view model. View models are agnostic - meaning that they don't have view objects in them (e.g. Listview, Buttons, etc..), but they are an object representation of the view (a.k.a the model of the view).

Comment: What you are saying makes sense.  I probably need to make a cleaner delineation between View and ViewModel, the two are not very separated right now (as I said, not a strict MVVM implementation at all).  So my solution was pushing stuff down to the model.  I think if I more properly architect the View and VIewModel, then your suggestion of keeping the highlighting control at the VIewModel makes sense and stops it from migrating down to the Model.

Comment: I would keep your models as lightweight as possible. It is debatable whether to put validation logic in them or not. I usually put only logic pertaining to the model itself. For example: